# Problem with support library android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity

Tags: android-actionbar, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I am using this to customize my action bar to have a uniform look on 2.1+ devices. And using the required theme with it. However, my problem is when I run the application on 2.3 devices the menu text color is white, hence, not readable due to white background other than that it work nicely on jelly bean device.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom and modify it with this:

```
 <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">#aabbcc</item>
```

I didn't confirm this though (I'm just pretty confident it will work).

Comment: Surely it should be <item name="actionMenuTextColor">#aabbcc</item> for pre Honeycomb themes. E.g. without the android namespace